# Chrome cookie сотни событий onChanged при открытии браузера

Tags: google-chrome, cookie

Простой код расширения на manifest v3 при запуске браузера вызывает сотни (да вообще все мои куки) срабатываний хотя открыта (стартовая) только страница chrome://extensions/ Даже после перезагрузки ПК

chrome.cookies.onChanged.addListener(function (changeInfo) {    console.log(changeInfo);});

Помогите пожалуйста как сделать что бы фальш срабатывания не было? Или как отличить  срабатывания на открытии браузера от использования браузера?

Comment: А полностью код расширения можно?